# how to draw canvas chart using ajax response data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvasjs

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

This is the output of my code as you see my response it has two keys day and amount. Day and Amount have values of array. Now when i am trying to push these values in empty array, it is not running. My chart is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax
   ({
type:'post',
url:'data.php',
success:function(response)
{
    var result= JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(result); //var count = Object.keys(result).length;
    //console.log(count);
    var dps =[]; 
    for(var i=0; i<result.length;i++)
    {
      dps.push({"label":result.day[i], "y":result.amount[i]});
    }
    console.log(dps);
   //Insert Chart-making function here
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
   zoomEnabled:true,
   panEnabled:true,
   animationEnabled:true,
   title:{
    text: "myChart from mySQL database"
  },

 axisX:{
    title: "TimeStamp"
 },

    axisY:{
    title: "myDataPoints",
    minimum: 0
 },

data: [{
    type: "spline",
    dataPoints:
        dps
          }]
});
chart.render();

}
   });
   });
```

[[02-Jan-16,413],[03-Jan-16,14],[04-Jan-16,2],[05-Jan-16,37],
[06-Jan-16,50],[07-Jan-16,22],[08-Jan-16,82]]
I also want to covert response data into this format.

This is the code of given output. Can anyone suggest how to do this.

Comment: First of all check with static data . chart is rendering or not

Comment: with static data chart is rendering

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<result.length;i++)` here is issue. Try `i<result.day.length`

Comment: Did you getting right format data  `console.log(dps);`  in dps array ?